# ASP.NET Core 2.2 targeting full framework 4.7.2 in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-4.7.2

I have an Application built using ASP.NET Core 2.2 (targeting full framework 4.7.2). It is running fine in VS 2017, But When I publish it to IIS, I get Process failed Error(HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure). I had this application working fine when I was using ASP.Net 2.0( I started Building the app on it). The Error was failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource. I used the publish option to publish the application. When I copied the release build folder contents the error changed to

> not able to load assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Then I added assembly redirect. Now it seems it was not able to load a specific type from one of my custom assemblies.

Everything is working fine in VS2017 in IIS Express

Comment: Have you updated the server bundle to 2.2?

Comment: No I haven't . I tried to run the release build as a console application then again I have the problem of 'not able to log type xxxx from assmebly ' error. But in VS2017 it is running

Comment: VS can update itself but it won’t update IIS. You have to configure IIS separately.

Comment: Now running a report should reveal the issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html